# Why does my code only write the first rows into my csv? I'm looping through multiple websites and print function seems to grab all the values

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape for a roster of all past Utah legislators from this website, and I was trying the most basic code to get that. My code can print out all the rows I need, but when I write it into csvs it only documents the first rows. What went wrong?

I thought it might be something wrong with the loop, but the print function seems to give out every row I want on that website. The following is my code:

```
import urllib2, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
outfile = open('ut_legislators.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)

letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

for l in letters:
    url = "https://le.utah.gov/asp/roster/complist.asp?letter=" + l
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'UItable'})
    rows = table.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        data = []
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        for cell in cells:
            data.append(cell.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
            writer.writerow(data)
```

And when I open the csv, it only returns the first rows.

Thanks!!

Comment: i.e you keep overwriting the file so you're only getting the last results

Comment: I see you are only opening the file once. If you wish to overwrite all data that is there whenever this code is called, then w is the correct way to open this. Try removing all contents from the file and seeing what this program outputs to the file then. If it is nothing I am assuming it is due to the file not being closed.

You can close the file outside of your for loops with outfile.close()

Comment: Oh nice. Yup y'all are right. I cleared the content and tried it one more time and it worked. I'm still rather new to python so I still have much to learn, but thanks for helping out!